# Object reference not set to an instance of an object ---- ERROR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting the following error :- Object reference not set to an instance of an object
in the following piece of code :-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then

            Dim entityClassID As Integer
            Dim entityCode As Integer
            entityClassID = "3"
            entityCode = "44"


            If Int32.TryParse(Request("ec").ToString(), entityClassID) AndAlso 
              Int32.TryParse(Request("code").ToString(), entityCode) Then
              EntityClass.InnerText = entityClassID.ToString()
              EntityIdentifier.InnerText = entityCode.ToString()
            End If

            Dim da As New DataAccess()

            userID.InnerText = da.GetCurrentUserID()
            userName.InnerText = da.GetCurrentUserName()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The  da As New DataAccess()  code does create an instance, but when da.GetCurrentUserID()
is called an exception is thrown as follows :-

```
Line 27:             Dim da As New DataAccess()
Line 28: 
Line 29:             userID.InnerText = da.GetCurrentUserID()
Line 30:             userName.InnerText = da.GetCurrentUserName()

Source File: D:\Dev\workpackage\WebSites\Workpackage\customised\workpackage\Index.aspx.vb    Line: 29 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlParameteredSqlParser.ExecuteScalar() +100
   UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlAccess.ExecuteScalar(String Source, XmlNode XmlQuery) +134
   UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlAccess.ExecuteScalar(String Source) +39
   UnionSquare.Workspace.User.GetUserIDFromLogonUser(HttpContext context) +89
   UnionSquare.Workspace.User.get_CurrentID() +162
   UnionSquare.Workspace.User.get_Current() +38
   WorkPackageLibrary.WorkPackageLibrary.DataAccess.GetCurrentUserID() +70
   Index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Dev\workpackage\WebSites\Workpackage\customised\workpackage\Index.aspx.vb:29
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Thanx in advance for any help that anyone might be able to provide

Regards

Ghostrider

Comment: There are *two* objects on line 29 (`userID` and `da`). Are you sure `userID` is valid?

Comment: Looks like the problem is inside your da.GetCurrentUserID() call.  You'll have to dig around in your DataAccess() class to find out what it's complaining about.

Comment: Can you include the GetCurrentUserID() in your question, my guess is the NullRef is bubbling from there.

Comment: UserID id Ok as indicated by others, I think the problem arises from
the GetCurrentUserID the code for which is as follows :- 



        Public Function GetCurrentUserID() As String

            Dim user As UnionSquare.Workspace.User = 
                            UnionSquare.Workspace.User.Current

            If user IsNot Nothing Then
                Return user.ID.ToString()
            Else
                Return "1"
            End If

        End Function


The problem I think lies within :- 
                  UnionSquare.Workspace.User.Current

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the stack trace you can tell that the exception is thrown from:

```
UnionSquare.Workspace.User.GetUserIDFromLogonUser(HttpContext context) +89
```

You need to look at this source.

P.S.
This is unrelated to your error but... The code where you initialize entityClassID & entityCode has to convert from string to int. It would make more sense to remove the quotes. You should look into setting [strict compilation option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) in your web.config to prevent accidents like this.

```
Dim entityClassID As Integer
Dim entityCode As Integer
entityClassID = "3"
entityCode = "44"
```

Should be changed to:

```
Dim entityClassID As Integer = 3
Dim entityCode As Integer = 44
```

Comment: Why the error can't be coming from `UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlAccess.ExecuteScalar(String Source) +39` or `UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlAccess.ExecuteScalar(String Source, XmlNode XmlQuery) +134`? I always found difficult to read stack traces... :\

Comment: @Albireo - It actually is but these are called by the line I pointed out. Just based on the method names it seemed like you would need to start there to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

The bug appears to be that the value `userName` or `userID` are `Nothing`.  Have you made sure that they are initialized before accessing them here?

Comment: If userID was null wouldn't it prevent DataAccess.GetCurrentUserID() from getting called? (Which it clearly is based on the stack trace)

Comment: @Seth no it wouldn't.  The `userId` value wouldn't be evaluated until after the `GetCurrentUserID()` function had completed.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So wouldn't the call to DataAccess.GetCurrentUserID() and below be out of the stack when the exception is thrown? Then the stack trace would just stop at Index.aspx.vb +29?

Comment: @Seth, As I look closer it looks like the error is in the function `UnionSquare.Workspace.Data.XmlParameteredSqlParser.ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 0):

As kd7 pointed out, the error is probably coming from `da.GetCurrentUserID()`, since if `userID` control does not exists the compiler would complain about it at build time. So, check that method.

Comment: Public Function GetCurrentUserID() As String

            Dim user As UnionSquare.Workspace.User =    UnionSquare.Workspace.User.Current

            If user IsNot Nothing Then
                Return user.ID.ToString()
            Else
                Return "1"
            End If

        End Function

Comment: @Ghostrider - You can't simply post the code of the function and expect us to magically find the error, you should place a breakpoint on `da.GetCurrentUserID()`, debug your application and dig into your code to find out what's causing the exception.

Comment: I have a break point at da.GetCurrentUserID an exception is thrown 
when this point is reached, debug will not allow me to step into the 
GetCurrentUserID() method. I think the problem may lie with me having 
to re register the DLL that GetCurrentUserID sits in